# Is there any way to prevent disk exhaustion from malicious continuous creation of PHP sessions?

Tags: php, security, backend, session-state

Lets say you get a page `index.php` which has a form inside of it, you need to start a session in the back-end which at least keeps a csrf token to validate against when the form is submitted. So, if every new user that gets `index.php` and does not have a valid session id cookie generates a new session, what is stopping me from setting up a request every 3 seconds eating up server disk space? Sessions aren't even considered garbage collection until 24 minutes by default. This gives me 480 requests per 24 minute cycle, and if every session is 4kb then I can take up 1,920,000 bytes (~2mb) per 24 min cycle.

How do I mitigate? Please help.

Comment: 2MB per 24 minutes equates to about 5MB per hour - which is about 8.5 days per GB

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure how 2MB/24min will ever exhaust your capacities, you could manually fire a call to [gc](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php) every minute or so and lower [maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).